# Sequence diagram which returns a boolean

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I want to know how to return a value in a sequence diagram, for example:

```
if(a>b) return true; 
else return false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two variants.

[image: lighter variant]
      
[image: heavier variant]

Please, notice, that dashed line means returning message. Solid line with parameters - calling message.

Full triangle arrow head means synchronous call.  Line angle triangle arrow head means asychronous call. But in the return message arrow ALWAYS has such head.

But if you really have so light cases as you have shown, it's better to use "alt" combined fragment directly, without all these three messages. Simply show in its two operands what you really do in these two branches.

Comment: i'm really sorry for your trouble, I know it was such a mediocre question to ask but back then i was just about to start learning UML and I wanted to know how to indicate the returned value of a sequence diagram. sorry once again for the inconvenient

Comment: @Namine Please, don't take an offence - but the question IS original (but in somewhat funny way). And IS useful (for the reason you mentioned in the comment). And original easy questions here mostly get the most upvotes here.