# Using conditional node in UML

Tags: if-statement, uml, conditional-statements, activity-diagram

I want to draw an activity diagram using "Software Ideas Modeler" software. and I need to have a conditional node in my diagram. I add the conditional node in my diagram but I don't know how should I change it according to my need. I couldn't find any solution related to my problem on internet. my condition would be something like this: 
If (x>30 && x<50) Set x+=5
Thanks for your help in advanced.

Comment: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-reference.html explains the `decision node` and there are 6 examples in http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-examples.html. What exactly have you tried, searched and what is it you don't know how?

Comment: Actually in software ideas modeler there is a tool named "condition node" which have three parts if, then and else. I don't know how to use that. should I write some codes in it or draw the diagram inside it. unfortunately there is nothing about it in software;s tutorial page.

Comment: I'm not sure if the tool falls into the _"..software tools commonly used.."_ category and if your non-programming question falls into the http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic category. I'd suggest opening a support request at http://www.softwareideas.net/Forum/4/Support and if that does not help then consider an affordable alternative tool with better support and more intuitive user interface

Comment: possible duplicate of [sequence diagram which returns a boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295166/sequence-diagram-which-returns-a-boolean)